# Solution fails to compile due to missing OperationFilterContext.ControllerActionDescriptor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate, swashbuckle

I just created and downloaded a sample project. It fails to compile due to a reference to `ControllerActionDescriptor` property of `OperationFilterContext` object:

```
public class SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        var actionAttrs = context.ControllerActionDescriptor.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true).ToList();
    }
}
```

I did update all NuGet packages. DLL hell will never go away :-(

Answer (score 9):

## `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` v2.5.0

`ControllerActionDescriptor` is only present in `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` v2.5.0.

See:
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/commit/c9777021ff3b7bd7900fb259779df8d3cba4e217#diff-e86edb6a6357b96238665ca2b11f5ab8

---

## `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` v3.0.0+

Now, you just need:

```
var controllerAttributes = context.MethodInfo.DeclaringType.GetCustomAttributes(true);
```

Comment: Thanks -- I ended up with this transformation:             var apiDescription = context.ApiDescription;
            var actionDescriptor = apiDescription.ActionDescriptor;
            var controllerActionDescriptor = actionDescriptor.AsControllerActionDescriptor();
            var actionAttrs = controllerActionDescriptor.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true).ToList();